# React in unable to work after adding import/export functionality

Tags: html, reactjs

Code was working perfectly when i did not create a module of the header tag but now it is not showing any error or rendering the page.

**Header.js**

```
export default function Header(){
    return(
        <header className="p-4 flex justify-between">
        <a href="" className="flex items-center gap-1">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" className="w-8 h-8 rotate-180">
          <path d="M19.006 3.705a.75.75 0 00-.512-1.41L6 6.838V3a.75.75 0 00-.75-.75h-1.5A.75.75 0 003 3v4.93l-1.006.365a.75.75 0 00.512 1.41l16.5-6z" />
          <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M3.019 11.115L18 5.667V9.09l4.006 1.456a.75.75 0 11-.512 1.41l-.494-.18v8.475h.75a.75.75 0 010 1.5H2.25a.75.75 0 010-1.5H3v-9.129l.019-.006zM18 20.25v-9.565l1.5.545v9.02H18zm-9-6a.75.75 0 00-.75.75v4.5c0 .414.336.75.75.75h3a.75.75 0 00.75-.75V15a.75.75 0 00-.75-.75H9z" clipRule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
        <span className='font-bold text-xl'>Bonkers</span>
        </a>
      
        <div className='flex gap-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-full px-2 py-1 shadow-md shadow-gray-500 '>
          <div>Anywhere</div>
          <div className='border border-l border-gray-300'></div>
          <div>Any Week</div>
          <div className='border border-l border-gray-300'></div>
          <div>Add Guests</div>
          <button className='bg-primary text-white p-1 rounded-full'>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6">
            <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M21 21l-5.197-5.197m0 0A7.5 7.5 0 105.196 5.196a7.5 7.5 0 0010.607 10.607z" />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      
        <Link to={'/login'} className='flex gap-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-full px-2 py-1'>
          <div className=''>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6 relative -bottom-1">
            <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M3.75 6.75h16.5M3.75 12h16.5m-16.5 5.25h16.5" />
            </svg>
          </div>
      
          <div className='bg-gray-500 text-white rounded-full p-1 border border-gray-300 overflow-hidden'>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6 relative">
            <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M15.75 6a3.75 3.75 0 11-7.5 0 3.75 3.75 0 017.5 0zM4.501 20.118a7.5 7.5 0 0114.998 0A17.933 17.933 0 0112 21.75c-2.676 0-5.216-.584-7.499-1.632z" />
            </svg>
      
          </div>
        </Link>
      </header>
    );
}
```

**IndexPage.js**

```
    import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
    import Header from "../Header.jsx";
    
    export default function IndexPage(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

in the import/export function there seems to be some kind of issue help me understand why is it not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xljtZ.png)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Webpage is not getting rendered only when i create header.js and put the contents of IndexPage in it

Comment: "What error are you getting" means *what error message are you getting*.  Have you looked at the console?

Answer (score 0):

for use of Link , NavLink , Route and ... , you need wrap your Component with BrowserRouter

```
export default function IndexPage(){
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Header />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
        
    );
}
```

Comment: Still not working after wrapping it up, link is not getting read

Comment: do you can add src/index.js to question?

Comment: it is better push your project on sandbox.